# Is Camera.stopPreview() and Camera.startPreview() methods necessary for setting camera flash modes in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, camera-api

I was recently trying to develop a flashlight application using the older Camera API. I get the Camera object by

```
camera = Camera.open();
p = camera.getParameters();
```

This is enclosed in try-catch block.The code I am using to turn on camera flash is

```
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(p);
```

This code given in try-catch block to handle exceptions and whether device support FLASH_MODE_TORCH is also checked. 
The code I am using to turn off camera flash is

```
p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
camera.setParameters(p);
```

This is also enclosed in try-catch block and the Camera object camera and Parameter object p are also defined correctly. My question is that do I need to "necessarily" use camera.startPreview() and camera.stopPreview() methods after setting camera parameters while turning on and turning off the flash light.?